# Rails I18n _html suffix rule and translate helper called from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

According to ruby [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate), the `translate` (or `t`) helper delegates to `I18n#translate` but also performs several additional functions, among which is: "it’ll mark the translation as safe HTML if the key has the suffix `_html`".

I would expect that it should work equally in both views and in controllers, but in my experience it doesn't: `t(:hello_html)` does work as expected in views (marks the translation as html_safe), but it does not mark the result as safe html when invoked from a controller.

To reproduce the problem you could add `hello_html: '<i>Hello world</i>'` to your `locales/en.yml` and `flash.now[:notice] = t(:hello_html)` to any convenient action of any controller. For me that resulted in an escaped html markup in a flash messages area which was an unexpected outcome for me.

My questions are:

1. is there anyone else who experienced or is able to reproduce this problem?
2. what is it: a rails bug, a feature, or just my project's unique "oddity"?
3. is there any easy way to work this around?

(Tested in rails 3.2.11 and 3.2.13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about this functionality not being available to controllers given that the overloaded `.t` method is defined in `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper`. I think this is probably an oversight as opposed to an actual bug.

Off the top of my head there are 2 ways you can get around this in your project :

1. Call `.html_safe` in your controller (this worked for me in a quick test).

   `flash[:notice] = t(:hello_html).html_safe`
2. Send the translation key as the flash message as opposed to the actual message :

   Controller :

   `flash[:translate_notice] = :hello_html`

   View :

   `%div= t flash[:translate_notice]`

Granted, the latter option might get a bit messy if you need to pass interpolations, YMMV.